# "Any G/Z(G) is Abelian in general" is this statement true or false?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can we prove or disprove the statement without an example? If the the statement is true then obviously there must exist a direct/indirect algebraic proof and in case the statement is wrong we must be able to reach a condition on G that will be necessary for G/Z(G) to be an Abelian group. I feel the statement is wrong but do not know how to prove it. please help.

Comment: To disprove $\forall G, G/Z(G)$ abelian, you must exhibit a group for which it is false, what don't you want an example? Indeed this is wrong, consider for example $A_5$.

Comment: Consider $S_3$.

Comment: No i don't want an example. I want algebraic proof

Comment: @SouravChakraborty : I believe proof is for statements which are true and counter example is for statements which are false..

Comment: Exhibiting an example *is* a proof: a statement of the form $\exists x . P(x)$ is proven by exhibiting a specific $x_0$ such that $P(x_0)$. Note that even if you found some algebraic criterion $P(G)$ (whatever you mean by algebraic) equivalent to $G/Z(G)$ being abelian, you would still be left with the burden of having to prove the existence of some group with the property $P(G)$.

Comment: If a statement is entirely wrong we must be able to prove it wrong because in mathematics T & F are in equal footing. Counter example is a convenient way of showing that certain statement is not true in general but a logical disproof must also exist if there exists something called proof.

Comment: an example is at best case specific unless we have an exhaustive set of examples. Which is impossible to obtain in most cases.

Comment: @SouravChakraborty: proving a statement $P$ wrong is proving $\neg P$ true in classical logic. The negation of this statement is $\exists G$ such that $G/Z(G)$ is not abelian. Proving an $\exist$-statement is done by exhibiting the desired object. This *is* a proof.

Comment: why cant I see entire messages? I only see them partially.

Comment: "In general" does not have a precise meaning in mathematics. You hear statements like "two straight lines in the plane intersect in a unique point in general", which means this is true for most pairs of lines (whatever that means), but in the context of your question it doesn't really mean anything. So you should just ask "Is $G/Z(G)$ abelian for all groups $G$?" and the answer is no, because (for example) it is false in $S_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would imply that every group with trivial center is abelian. Which is of course wrong: The symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$ has trivial center for $n>2$ and is not abelian.

If $G$ is a group, then $G/Z(G)$ is abelian iff the [upper central series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series) stops at $2$.